# ExtJS - Differentiate items in MultiSelect

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have 2 `MultiSelects` in an `ItemSelector`, itself in a `FormPanel`. Each `MultiSelect` is composed of 2 `Stores`: left side, and right side (with arrows to move items between the 2).

When I load the panel, I feed a reference, in order to highlight the items moved from one side to the other (e.g. set style as red for moved items) because today there is no way to differentiate them.

I managed to catch event `afterAdd` on  the `Stores` and apply my style through DOM access. That works during trace, but later on remaining ExtJS standard calls are performed, overriding the style I just applied...

I feel what I'm doing is not the good way, but I'm new to ExtJS so I'm a bit lost here... Thanks for your help !

**EDIT :** here is a sample of my code, I forgot to tell that I worked on ExtJS 3.2 (hum...). `pool_cnx_to_rule` is my `FormPanel`:

```
pool_cnx_to_rule.afterMethod('add', function ()
{
    //var pools_available_ = Ext.getCmp('pools_available').getValue();
    var pools_selected_ = Ext.getCmp('pools_selected').getValue();
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < pool_cnx_to_rule.data.length; ++i)
    {
        var pool_descr_ = pool_cnx_to_rule.data.items[i].data.pool_descr;
        var changed = true;
        for (j = 0; j < pool_cnx_to_rule_ref.length; ++j)
        {
            if (pool_cnx_to_rule_ref[j] == pool_descr_)
            {
                changed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (changed)
        {
            var pools_selected_ = Ext.getCmp('pools_selected');
            var nodes_ = pools_selected_.view.getNodes();
            var node_ = nodes_[j];
            var record_ = pools_selected_.view.getRecord(node_);
            record_.set('color', 'red');
            // Instead of assigning pools_selected_.view, create var
            var view_ = new Ext.ListView({
                multiSelect: true,
                store: pools_selected_.store,
                columns: [{
                    dataIndex: pools_selected_.displayField,
                    header: 'Value',
                    width: 1,
                    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                        '<tpl if="red==true">',
                        '<div class="red">{' + pools_selected_.displayField + '}</div>',
                        '<tpl else>',
                        '<div>{' + this.displayField + '}</div>',
                        '</tpl>'
                        ),
                }],
                hideHeaders: true
            });
            pools_selected_.fs.items.clear();
            pools_selected_.fs.add(view_);
            pools_selected_.fs.doLayout();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: lol :) Ext 3.2, small detail you forgot to mention here :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm currently whipping myself for that :)

Answer (score 4):

**For Ext 4.2**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/mXLtG/) is a fiddle which colors the records you choose. (to use it, select some items and press 'red'..)
It does not take care of adding and catching events only the coloring of selected items, as I understand this is the problematic part for you.

Basically I added a listConfig to the multiSelection, which transfers it to it's boundList:

```
listConfig: {
    itemTpl: '<div class="my-boundlist-item {color}">{numberName}</div>',
}
```

The template is getting it's values from the multiselect store, so we can just set the "color" field for the records we want:

```
myRecord.set('color', 'red');
```

By doing this the item which we set will now have the class 'red'. Last thing was to add css for the class:

```
.red {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Note that I made it quite transparent, so the selection and hovering color will still be noticeable.

**For Ext 3.2**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/VJABm/) is the fiddle. As @VDP mentioned, Ext 3.2 uses ListView for the multiselect, which can get a tpl config (templatecolumn is actually not available for listview, just for grid)

However MultiSelect doesn't expose this config, so we have to override the onRender of multiselect, here is the interesting part:

```
Ext.ux.form.ConfigurableMultiSelect = Ext.extend(Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect,  {
    listItemTpl: null,

    onRender: function(ct, position){
        ...
        var listItemTpl = this.listItemTpl || '<div>{'+this.displayField+'}</div>';

        this.view = new Ext.ListView({
            multiSelect: true,
            store: this.store,
            columns: [{  
                dataIndex: this.displayField,
                header: 'Value',
                width: 1,
                tpl: listItemTpl
            }],
            hideHeaders: true
        });
        ...
```

Now we can use the extended class to pass a listItemTpl config to the view:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'confmultiselect', //the new xtype we registered
    fieldLabel: 'Multiselect',
    name: 'multiselect',
    id: 'multiselect-field',
    allowBlank: false,
    displayField: 'text',
    store: store,
    listItemTpl: '<div class="inner-boundlist-item {color}">{text}</div>',
}],
```

The rest is pretty much the same as in Ext 4.2

Comment: Wow, impressive ! I had a deep look at your solution, since I'm on 3.x the `MultiSelect` is used a bit differently (in an `ItemSelector`, see my edit for the code) so I don't think I can specify an `id` to handle it later on. Am I right ?

Comment: Thanks :) No, you can't use my solution with Ext 3.2, but for the reasons specified by @VDP, which is pointing you at the right direction, with his update. I might implement a fiddle for 3.2, if I find the time today.

Comment: Edited with implementation for Ext 3.2

Comment: Yes, thanks ! I tried to implement your solution, but the `onRender` function is definitely not called. I then created a function that does quite the same (except call the parent's function), but this has no effect on my fields: they are not changed (not red obviously, and no new class applied). Is this a matter of moment (I catch the `add` event on my store, as shown above, thanks to a `afterMethod(''add')`), or ... ?

Comment: I will write the full solution later, but to make the ItemSelector use the extended MultiSelect, you will have to override the onRender method of ItemSelector. Look at the code http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-3.2.0/examples/ux/ItemSelector.js and change the following line this.toMultiselect = new Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect(Ext.applyIf(this.multiselects[1], msConfig[1])); to use Ext.ux.form.ConfigurableMultiSelect

Comment: Actually it will be easier to use Ext.override just for MultiSelect, instead of Ext.extend. And keep ItemSelector as is, sorry for the confusion, just woke up.. :)

Comment: Well, not far now: I edited my post to show you the last state of my code. Setting color works but... this duplicates the items shown (and in `fs` object too during trace) !!! I tried to remove elements from `fs` (`pools_selected_.fs.items.clear()`) but this does not work. I also tried to use a local view instead of assigning it to my `MultiSelect` but this does not work either.

Comment: To answer a question you might ask: if I override the `fs` as you do in the fiddle (`var fs = pools_selected_.fs = new Ext.form.FieldSet...`), then nothing new happens (no color change, no duplicates).

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear for me when you want it to be marked.

What I would do is attach a listener on the store of the `fromField` and/or the `toField`

Lets say we want all items, removed from the toField, marked:

```
// somewhere after setupItems (that's where the lists got created)

itemSelector.toField.store.on('remove', itemSelector.onRemoveItem);
onRemoveItem = function(record){
    record.set('removed', true);
}

// on the 'Ext.view.BoundList' of the fromField I would change my itemTpl and
// check if removed is true in the template. If so, add a class

// refresh the list
```

It's not a ready-made solution but maybe this gets you on track...

UPDATE:

@Amit Aviv just wrote in detail what I meant with 'change' the itemTpl to add a class

what I had in mind was something like this:

```
listConfig: {
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl if="removed==true">',
            '<div class="my-boundlist-item removed">{value}</div>',
        '<tpl else>',
            '<div class="my-boundlist-item">{value}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    )
}
```

The rest is the same. Amit's solution is just as good ;)

In Ext 3 and itemselector contains 2 `Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect`. A MultiSelect has a Ext.ListView where in Ext 4 it uses a BoundList. This ListView is very similar to a grid.

It has no itemTpl, but it has columns. You can override onRender of the MultiSelect so you can  insert your own column in the ListView. This is the part to be modified:

```
this.view = new Ext.ListView({
    multiSelect: true,
    store: this.store,
    columns: [{ header: 'Value', width: 1, dataIndex: this.displayField }],
    hideHeaders: true
});
```

Can be something like this:

```
this.view = new Ext.ListView({
    multiSelect: true,
    store: this.store,
    columns: [{ xtype: 'templatecolumn',
        header: 'Value',
        width: 1,
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl if="removed==true">',
                '<div class="removed">{' + this.displayField + '}</div>',
            '<tpl else>',
                '<div>{' + this.displayField + '}</div>',
            '</tpl>'
        )
    }],
    hideHeaders: true
});
```

or you can modify it after rendering... your choice :)

Comment: Thanks, my 1st answer :-) I may be unclear indeed. There is no problem for me to compute the differences - I just can't apply a different STYLE to the items changed from the original.

Comment: I did what Amit suggested, i.e. override `onRender` function for custom `MultiSelect`, but it looks like this method is never called (I use Firebug and breakpoints) during the process which consists in moving an item from one `MultiSelect` to the other one.